# cannot insert INTO table

Tags: php, mysql

> **Use of undefined constant ugDept - assumed 'ugDept'**

this error is appearing when i try to execute the code below

```
$_10thPercentage=number_format($_POST['tenthPercentage'], 2, '.', ' ');
$query="
INSERT INTO academic 
    VALUES (
        '".$_SESSION['roll']."', 
        '".$_POST[tenthMedium]."',
        ".$_10thPercentage.",
        '".$_POST[twelthStudiedStatus]."',
        ".$_10thPercentage.",
        '".$_POST[techStudiedStatus]."',
        '".$_POST[techDept]."',
        '".$_POST[techPercentage]."',
        '".$_POST[appStudiedStatus]."',
        '".$_POST[appDept]."',
        '".$_POST[appPercentage]."',
        '".$_POST[ugStudiedStatus]."',
        '".$_POST[ugDept]."',
        '".$_POST[ugCgpa]."',
        '".$_POST[pgStudiedStatus]."',
        '".$_POST[pgDept]."',
        '".$_POST[pgCgpa]."')";

mysql_query($query);
```

Only certain value will be passed to the post. so the code is not working suggest some way to solve it

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 11):

You may need to change all your $_POST variables to use quotes (if you aren't using constants). Like so:

```
$_POST['ugDept']
```

Otherwise, PHP looks for a constant value named **ugDept**, which may not exist. If you are using constants, make sure you've defined it properly. You can do that like so:

```
define('ugDept', 'someValueHere');
```

Also, as others have suggested, **you need to sanitize your inputs** and **you should be using [the Mysqli extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), not `mysql_*`**. As it is now, your database is at risk of a SQL injection, which is bad.

**Update:** To make sure your `mysql_query` call is succeeding or not, do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query('{YOUR QUERY HERE}');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This will report the SQL error to you. Note that `die`ing isn't necessarily the best thing to do in a production environment; but in development, it does the job.

Comment: All the errors are cleared but data is not inserting into database

Comment: Are you testing to see if your SQL query succeeded or not? If it's not, what error string is being returned? You essentially have to check for errors at each step in the process. Also, you should be using the MySQLi extension, not the `mysql_*` functions. The `mysql_*` functions will be deprecated eventually.

Comment: @JonahBishop that's problem it is not even showing a single error. But the value is not inserting.

Comment: You should be testing the result of your `mysql_query` call. I'll add that portion to my answer.

Comment: I would upvote if you'd at least mentioned `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Truth ... Ha, I mentioned it in one of my comments. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also look into sanitizing your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your constact `ugDept` is not defined. Just define it like you must have done with for example `tenthMedium`

Answer (score 0):

$_10thPercentage isn't taken from the post array, should it be? Also a create statement for the table would be helpful.

Comment: Look at the first line friend.